# Kafka: delete key?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've got a Kafka set up with compaction on. To delete some entries, I did send tombstone messages to the topics, sadly mistyping some keys.

**Is it possible to remove/clean up keys?**

Answer (score 0):

If you have tombstone messages with mistyped keys they will eventually be removed anyway from the compacted topic. Otherwise the is no other way to remove a particular key out of a topic.

Note, that you can have `cleanup.policy` set to `compact` and `delete` at the same time. Making use of that, any message with a mistyped key will disappear after the retention time.